# internal error at the local server node.js

Tags: node.js

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Command failed: npm ERR! extraneous: mongoose@3.8.0 /Users/geek/Desktop/Projects/Tao/TaoKe/node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR! not ok code 0

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

[image]

When i used the Nide to open the project then the problem comes!

Comment: Could you please format all of it, and then give us some background? What were you trying to do? What is the environment? Finally, a guess: go ahead and delete `/Users/geek/Desktop/Projects/Tao/TaoKe/node_modules/mongoose` then re-try.

Comment: I use the nide to code project..and yesterday i closed the pc!when i open the project by nide again ,the problems come.!

Comment: As ur say it works,but i need the mongoose!

Comment: @Goper-Alex: Please add your package.json.

Comment: Have you started your mongoDB? If yes, then check connection url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find module 'ejs' - Node.js app on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955388/cannot-find-module-ejs-node-js-app-on-heroku)